# How to make a function wait for jobs to finish

Tags: powershell

I have many functions running one by one and some require time to finish, so I want the function to only continue once done.

Is there a smarter way of writing this?

```
function myJob {
    $proc = Start-Process -Wait -FilePath $procPath -ArgumentList $argument
    return $proc.ExitCode
}

do { sleep 1 } while(Get-Process -Name { myJob } -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
```

or for a more generalized

```
function myJob {
    #do stuff
}
do { sleep 1 } while(Get-Process -Name { myJob } -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
```

Comment: add parameter `-PassThru` to your `start-process`. Then you can use `$proc.WaitForExit()`.

Comment: This isn't valid code. I can't say I've ever tried passing a ScriptBlock to `Get-Process -Name`  but no matter what I try I get the error `Cannot evaluate parameter 'Name' because its argument is specified as a script block and there is no input. A script block cannot be evaluated without input.` This is to be expected when using a scriptblock where one can't be used as an argument

Comment: Also if you want to run the process and wait why is `Start-Process -Wait` not enough here?